# Get only the SELECTED cells of a jQuery DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I found many examples but not "as low-level" as I'd wish.
I can print all the rows with this:

```
    var r = table.rows( { selected: true } )
     for(i=0; i<r.count(); ++i) {
       console.log('data:' + table.row(r[i]).data())
     }
```

This would be ALMOST perfect, but it prints all the cells separated by a comma. Why is it wrong? Because it doesn't escape the commas in the cells in any way, so if there is a comma, I have no way to know if it's a cell separator or an innocent comma.

I tried to get the first column with

```
    var r = table.rows( { selected: true } )
    for(i=0; i<r.count(); ++i) {
      console.log('data2:'+table.row( r[i] ).cells(0).data())
      console.log('data3:'+table.row( r[i] ).cells(0))
    }
```

And while there is no error, they give back an Object that I cannot find the properties of.
I wish there could be a method like

```
    console.log('table.row( r[i] ).cells(0).toString())
```

but I couldn't find any. Even better, I wish I could have a table.cells[4,3] :) :) :)

Comment: can you share you code properly with html as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find data in selected row with below block of code -

Example 1 :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
 
$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {

    //Below Line of Code will give full line of selected on clicked row in datatable
    console.log( table.row( this ).data() );

    //Below Line of Code will give column data [0] mean first column
    console.log( table.row( this ).data()[0] );
});
```

Another Code Block with printing of every column value or extracting it from row.

you can find data in selected row with below block of code -

Example 2 :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
 
$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {

    //Get Columns Count
    var count=$("#example thead tr th").length;

    for(i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
       //Below line of Code will print data of every column inside selected row.
       // you can also use and array to collect column data.
       console.log( table.row( this ).data()[i] );

    }
});
```

Example 3 : This below code block will give you single / multiple selected rows with loop and another loop to get its columsn data its not using `(this)`

```
//Set Reference to Table Tag
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

//Get Selected Rows of Datatable one or multiple
var r=table.rows( { selected: true } );

//Get Columns Count
var count=$("#example thead tr").length;

for(i=0;i<count;i++)
{
    //Below line of Code will print data of every row
    console.log(r.data()[i]);
    
    //To Get Each Cell Data Inside Row use below code block
    var cell_count=$("#example thead tr th").length;

    //Loop on cells inside row
    for(cell=0; cell < cell_count; cell++)
    {
       //Get Cell Inside Row
       var _cell=r.data()[cell];

       $.each( _cell, function( key, value ) {
          console.log( "Cell "+key + " : " + value );
       });

    }
}
```

Selected Rows in Jquery Datatable :

[image: Selected Rows in Jquery Datatable]

Comment: Thank you. The .data()[i] is almost everything I was looking for. Still, in the example provided it's "easy" because you HAVE "this" from the event. I was looking for a "low level", meaning doing it myself, for loop to iterate through all the cells, WITHOUT having someone passing me "this".

Comment: @ZioBit that is also achievable. let me update my answer

Comment: @ZioBit I have updated answer with "low level" without using 'this'. it will give you the row to extract columns

Comment: Thank you for it but there is an error:  var _cell=r.data()[i]; should be [cell], not [i]. Unfortunately I cannot edit it (it says edit must be 6 chars long) so either I put some dummy edits, or maybe you can do it? :)

Comment: @ZioBit you are right thank you i update it.